# How to show a UIWebView after UITableViewCell is selected?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview

I currently have my root view controller as a TableViewController with a NavigationController.

```
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FeedTableViewController(style: .grouped))
```

When a cell is selected, in my TableViewController, I would like to load a WebView with a string of HTML.

My code is currently:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let layout = TableViewLayout(indexPath: indexPath) else { fatalError() }
        switch layout {
        case .items:
            // load web view with html from a string
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

I have seen how to load a string of HTML into a WebView, but I don't know how to make that WebView the view that is shown when a cell is selected. I also need this to not break the NavigationController if possible.

Comment: where is your webview ? In another viewcontroller or the same as your table ? is this implemented via storyboard or programmatically ?

Comment: @GIJOW Programmatically. I don't have the WebView at all. I need to create one and I'm not sure where

Comment: But you want to show it in the same viewcontroller as your table ?

Comment: Yes, if that preserves the NavigationController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite hard by your comments to know "if that preserves NavigationController".

But I think it can at least give you a clue:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let layout = TableViewLayout(indexPath: indexPath) else { fatalError() }
        switch layout {
        case .items:
             let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.frame.size.height)
             let testHTML = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "privacy", ofType: "html")
             do {
                 let contents = try NSString(contentsOfFile: testHTML!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                 let baseUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: testHTML!) //for load css file
                 webView.loadHTMLString(contents as String, baseURL: baseUrl as URL)
             } catch {
                print("error")
             }
             self.view.addSubview(webView)
        default:
            break
        }
}
```

It will add a webView in same frame as your table view.

Don't forget to set up your html origin:

```
let testHTML = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "privacy", ofType: "html")
```

Comment: I am no longer able to go back to my TableView, but I think I may be able to solve that. Your answer provided much clarity.

Comment: glad to help. I've just updated the answer for a "more swifty 3". Hope it helps